# How to change the value of a field in SharedPreferences every couple of hours?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to edit a value in SharedPreferences of my application without any user's actions every couple of hours or at the specific time (e.g. every 00:00). How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Use service to do this.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Are you asking how to change/edit a value in shared preferences, or how to execute some code periodically(hourly)?